# How to implement system bars insets with edge-to-edge gesture navigation?

Tags: android, kotlin, windowinsets, edge-to-edge

I'm trying to add the [edge-to-edge stuff](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/edge-to-edge) for the gesture navigation bar to the [Tip Time app from Google](https://github.com/google-developer-training/android-basics-kotlin-tip-calculator-app-solution). I added the transparent `navigationBarColor` XML tag to `themes.xml` as well as the following code to the `onCreate()` function of `MainActivity.kt`:

[image: android edge-to-edge code error]

This was directly copy-pasted from the documentation. Android Studio says that "it cannot find a parameter with this name" for each of the three margins. I noticed that changing the parenthesis right after `<ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams>` to curly braces fixes the compiler error. Maybe the documentation is just wrong?

Anyways, even after fixing that, the app still doesn't look right:

[image: android edge-to-edge emulator error]

As you can see, the entire view gets shifted up slightly and the "Cost of Service" `TextView` is partially cut-off by the app bar. What would I need to change to implement the system/navigation bar insets for edge-to-edge content so the UI looks nice? Also, as a side-question, how can I change the dark blue color of the system status bar to match the color of the app bar so that they look blended?

Comment: What is the layout type of the `binding.root` ?

Comment: It's a `ScrollView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per documentation for [edge to edge contents](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/edge-to-edge):

> Draw behind the status bar if it makes sense for your content and
> layout, such as in the case of full-width imagery. To do this, use
> APIs such as AppBarLayout, which defines an app bar pinned to the top
> of the screen.

So, while handing the window insets (especially the top one), you can't use the default `ActionBar`, instead you need to customize that with `AppBarLayout` and `ToolBar`, and to make it act as the `ActionBar`, use `setSupportActionBar()`, and a `NoActionBar` app theme; it'd be `<style name="Theme.TipTime" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">` in the shared repo.

> the entire view gets shifted up slightly and the "Cost of Service" text field is partially cut-off by the app bar.

The reason that the sample uses the default `ActionBar` instead of a customized one; when it comes to handle the top window insets, it won't affect the default `ActionBar`; notice that you pass in the activity's root layout to `setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener` callback, and as the `ActionBar` is not a part of the activity, it won't be affected. Therefore the activity  is shifted up behind the `ActionBar` when the top inset is removed. So, to solve this you have either to totally remove the default `ActionBar` or to use a custom toolbar instead.

> Also, as a side-question, how can I change the dark blue color of the system status bar to match the color of the app bar so that they look blended?

Use a transparent status bar color in the app's theme:

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

Comment: Thank you! Also, for anyone else who stumbles across this, you only need `topMargin = insets.top` if you remove the `ActionBar` and not the other margins.

Comment: Hey, I'm having trouble again getting it to play nicely with another project that contains a bottom navigation bar. I tried different combinations of top and bottom margins, but the system navigation bar doesn't blend in with the bottom navigation bar: https://i.imgur.com/CdnL7QF.png

Comment: It is set to transparent in my `themes.xml` as well. I also noticed that including only the `WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)` and not the `ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(binding.root)` works, but the content ends up being layed underneath the system status bar: https://i.imgur.com/q95E7cw.png

Comment: @dem I think this is  something different; the RecyclerView probably needs to be constrainted on top of the bottom navigation bar; could you share this layout?

Comment: How about `android:layout_height="0dp"` in the FragmentContainerView?